# Why selection-statement allows using of ; expression-statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, expression, language-lawyer, grammar

It allows the constructs like:

```
if (0);
if (0); else;
```

Why allowing of such constructs?

Can the simplification of the grammar be the reason?

Comment: `if(condition_that_is_far_less_readable_when_negated) ; else { logic }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some sample use cases for null statements are:

The work is all done in the enclosing statement:

```
// Count length of a string.
for (length = 0; buffer[length] != 0; ++length)
    ;
```

The case is part of a group whose organization you want to be visually clear:

```
if      (parameter <  .3)
    CorrectVeryLow();
else if (parameter <  .9)
    CorrectLow();
else if (parameter < 1.1)
    ;
else if (parameter < 1.7)
    CorrectHigh();
else
    CorrectVeryHigh();
```

The case arises from preprocessor selections in which sometimes there is work to be done and sometimes there is not:

```
#if FeatureTest
    #define InitializeSpecialFeature SetupSpecialFeature()
#else
    #define InitializeSpecialFeature
#endif

…

if (TimeToReset)
    InitializeSpecialFeature;
```

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon `;` can be used by itself to be an empty statement.

Which means that

```
if (0);
```

is equivalent to

```
if (0)
{
    // Empty
}
```

And

```
if (0); else;
```

is equivalent to

```
if (0)
{
    // Empty
}
else
{
    // Also empty
}
```

Comment: The "1 empty" can be useful. How "2 empties" can be useful?

Comment: @pmor : Ask yourself that question; that was the code _you_ wrote in _your_ question.  The likely use of this however would be in a macro with a conditionally compiled selection of an expression-statement or an empty macro; the null statement being necessary to maintain syntactic validity.  It is a different question however; if you need detail, post a new question.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing unusual or exceptional going on here, and specifically no "*simplification of the grammar"*.  It is entirely consistent.  It is a matter of what constitutes a "*statement*".  The syntax is:

```
if( <expression> ) <statement> [else <statement>]
```

Where `<statement>` takes a number of forms:

```
statement:
 labeled-statement
 expression-statement
 compound-statement
 selection-statement
 iteration-statement
 jump-statement
```

but specifically `expression-statement` is:

```
expression-statement:
 expression(optional) ;
```

so `;` on its own is a valid *expression-statement*.

It is for the the same reason that the following is a valid and well-formed C program:

```
int main()
{
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: The `if (0); else { /* logic */ }` can be useful. How `if (0); else;` can be useful?

Comment: @pmor  I am not saying it is useful - you proposed that code, not me!  I am simply explaining how it is syntactically valid.  `validity != usefulness`.  C has a simple grammar that allows you to do dumb things, but makes compilers rather easier to implement.  Just like in a natural spoken language, a _grammatically_ correct construct can still be _semantic_ nonsense.  In some cases the statement may be a macro that under conditional compilation resolves to either something or _do nothing_.  In that circumstance the null-statement is useful to maintain syntactic validity under different builds.

Comment: _C has a simple grammar that allows you to do dumb things, but makes compilers rather easier to implement._: this is what I've meant under "simplification of the grammar".

Comment: @pmor "simplification" suggests an active process of making something simpler. C was always simple, nothing has been simplified.  Perhaps you meant "simplicity of the grammar".